# Pass dynamically generated value to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting data from controller and displaying in a JSP page as follows:

```
<li>
    <a class="groupList" href="#" onclick="myfunction(${item.id})">
        ${item.name}
    </a> 
</li>
```

Now I want to call a jquery function on click of an item, which in turn will be  ajax call to perform some operations depending on the id passed to the function.

Any help?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have above?  It looks fine to me, unless the id isn't numeric.

Comment: OP want to call jquery function and not javascript

Comment: how can you call a jquery fuction with this code? -1 for that?

Comment: He means Javascript function.  OP doesn't realise that jQuery is simply a Javascript library, built with Javascript.  That's not his problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : you can store id of item in some data attribute and register click event handler for elmement using come class as shown below

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a class="groupList" href="#" data-item-id="${item.id}">
        ${item.name}
    </a> 
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function(){
    $(document).on("click","a.groupList",function(){
        var itemId = $(this).data("item-id");
        //use this itemId for ajax call
    });
 });
```